# vlookup with 2 columns in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having an issue with vlookup using 2 columns. I have the following 2 columns in my base excel sheet

```
ID_1   ID2
2       4
7       9
```

and my target sheet has these values

```
ID    spend
2     20
4     30
7     10
1     5
9     10
```

When I run my vlookup, I would like to get this result

```
ID_1   ID2   Total_Spend
2       4      50
7       9      20
```

I am using something like this for Total_Spend, but it is not working..

```
=iferror(vlookup,0)+iferror(vlookup,0)
```

Comment: That works for me, what are the vlookups you are using?

Comment: it is not summing up the values

Comment: As I said, it works for me,  what are the vlookups you are using?  I used: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,E:F,2,FALSE),0)+IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,E:F,2,FALSE),0)` and it correctly found and summed the two.  The error is with the vlookups not what you have shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can use `SUMIF()`

[image]

Here the formula in `D4` is:

```
=SUMIF($B$9:$B$13,B4,$C$9:$C$13)+SUMIF($B$9:$B$13,C4,$C$9:$C$13)
```